# Numerical method for solving a polynomial equation

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I am looking for a numerical solution of a equation which contains, in general, one polynomial equation with unknown variable x. I have tried `Reduce`, `Solve`, `NSolve` and `FindRoot`, but I'm getting nothing after running my code for a few days. Probably there is solution in some of numerical iterative or other methods, unknown for me.

```
 a1 = Sqrt[2*10^11*3.055*10^-5];
 a2 = 0.01;
 a3 = 7849;
 a4 = 10;
 a5 = 50;
 a6 = 11;
 a7 = 700;

 k1 = Rationalize[
 Solve[(k (k^3 a1 - I a2 - k (a4 + a5^2 a3)) + x - 2 k a5 a3 a6 - 
      a3 a6^2) == 0, k][[4]][[1]][[2]], 0];
 k2 = Rationalize[
 Solve[(k (k^3 a1 - I a2 - k (a4 + a5^2 a3)) + x - 2 k a5 a3 a6 - 
      a3 a6^2) == 0, k][[1]][[1]][[2]], 0];
 k3 = Rationalize[
 Solve[(k (k^3 a1 - I a2 - k (a4 + a5^2 a3)) + x - 2 k a5 a3 a6 - 
      a3 a6^2) == 0, k][[3]][[1]][[2]], 0];
 k4 = Rationalize[
 Solve[(k (k^3 a1 - I a2 - k (a4 + a5^2 a3)) + x - 2 k a5 a3 a6 - 
      a3 a6^2) == 0, k][[2]][[1]][[2]], 0];

 expr = (I  a1 (k1 - k3) (k2 - k3) (k1 - k4) (k2 - k4))/(
 k1 + k2 - k3 - k4) - a7 a6^2;

 NSolve[expr == 0, x]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are at least two solutions (real or "almost real"):
You can get initial approximations from the following plot:

```
Plot[Log[Abs[expr]], {x, 3.8 10^10, 4.0 10^10}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

To get more accurate results use `FindRoot`

```
FindRoot[expr, {x, 3.85 10^10}] (* x->3.84004 10^10-0.609932 I*)
FindRoot[expr, {x, 3.95 10^10}] (* x->3.94883 10^10-0.631114 I*)
```

Comment: how to be sure that there are only two roots. I know that all of them should be complex, but more then two. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I found only two roots. The problem is that analytical expressions for `k1, k2, k3, k4` involves square roots. That means that analytic continuation of these functions (in case of complex `x`) is multivalued... So either function `expr` should be treated as multivalued or it will wave branch cuts (that depends on the problem you were solving in the first place).